# remove and replace xml tag

Tags: regex, xml

I have a string of xml and I need to change the name of one element.

```
string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
```

I returns some xml

```
<MfeEpeExportMachineKeys>text of some sort</MfeEpeExportMachineKeys>
```

I just want to remove the s off the end so it looks like this

```
<MfeEpeExportMachineKey>this is a parent tag`enter code here`</MfeEpeExportMachineKey>
```

But I can't use other examples I have seen because they remove the s from other elements as well. I just want to remove the s from this single element. not the others such as:

```
</entries>This is a child tag</entries>
```

Comment: Don't use regexes to process xml if an xml parser is availalbe.

Comment: Either use an xml parser library or use XSLT.  This would be very simple to write up an XSLT transform for this.  Regexes are a terrible tool for xml parsing.  You can usually write one that will work on a particular file, but it will probably break on the next one - there are too many edge cases to keep track of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other mentioned in the comment, using REGEX is a terrible tool for xml parsing. Anyway here is REGEX solution:

```
/(<\/?\w+)\w>/g
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uD5hQ9/4)

- `/(` delimiter and capturing group
- `\/?` matches slash in the string if it exists
- `\w+` matches any word characters *(one or more)*
- `\w` last character
- `>` matches `>` character in the string